# How to install Open JRE in RHEL 8.3 without registration

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, jre, openjdk

When I try to install packages to RHEL 8.3, I see :

```
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Unable to read consumer identity.
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
```

is there an alternative way without registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK)
is now maintained by the community, as Oracle has abandoned free support.

There is no separate JRE anymore, only the JDK which includes all JRE parts (e.g. the java binary). Do not use OracleJDK unless you intend to pay for it. OpenJDK is the new default.

[AdoptOpenJDK.net](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)
provides JDK and JRE builds that you can use without paying a license fee.